# _replace does not call __new__ of a named tuple subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

I have this subclass of a named tuple type:

```
class User(namedtuple('User', ['first_name'])):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        if not result.first_name:
            raise InvalidUserError({InvalidUserError.EMPTY_FIRST_NAME})
        return result
```

Creating a new user works as expected:

```
>>> try: User(first_name='')
... except Exception as e: print(type(e))
<class 'InvalidUserError'>
```

However, when `_replace` is used the `__new__` method is not invoked:

```
>>> User(first_name='foo')._replace(first_name='')
User(first_name='')
```

Is there a way to guarantee invariants with `namedtuple`? I'm using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python in general relies on conventions and good documentation rather than on strongly enforcing invariants.  Even without `_replace()`, you could circumvent `User.__new__()`:

```
>>> class X(tuple): __slots__ = ()
>>> x = C(('',))
>>> x.__class__ = User
>>> x
User(first_name='')
```

So no, you will never be able to stricly enforce this.  Simply avoid using `_replace()`, or override it with a version that does call `User.__new__()`, or check the invariants at a different level.

An example implementation of `_replace()`:

```
def _replace(self, **kwargs):
    return type(self)(**dict(vars(self), **kwargs))
```

Comment: My point is not preventing ugly hacks like your example, but rather supporting code I would actually write, which would most certainly use `User(...)` and `user._replace(...)`.

Comment: @PolymorphicPotato: In that case, you'll have to override `_replace()` with your own version, e.g. `User(**dict(vars(some_user), first_name='Joe'))`.

Comment: That should work. I might even be able to create some base class or decorator to do that for me!